# Showing PHP Errors in Nginx Instead of 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, error-handling, nginx

How do I show PHP errors instead of nginx's 502 Bad Gateway error? I have all error reporting on but anytime I cause a fatal error the PHP error information is not passed to the browser.

Comment: 502 errors doesn't mean that php has an error, it means that nginx couldn't connect or communicate with the php server, make sure that php-cgi/fpm is running, php errors are displayed as 500 error, and not all the time

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a route file to dispatch urls;
2. Use try/catch in route file to catch all exceptions;
3. Show custom 502 page when catch exceptions.

eg:
Nginx configuration:

error_page 502      http://example.com/502.html;